# Display custom comment field in admin

Tags: 7, entities, comments

I created some custom fields for the comment form for specific content types.

One field for instance is the email fields, it's used to contact posts after they won a contest.

But when I look at the comments in the admin, there is no option to view these custom fields.
Is there a way to change this?

So I want to add custom fields to the admin overlay for comments

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create a view for that, and select which fields to show.

Comment: I don't want to show it on the website, I want to show it in the admin overlay where all comments are shown (#overlay=admin/content/comment)

Comment: yeah, you can create a view with the path admin/content/comment/custom